# Write a List Into Excel File with Python

Tags: python, excel, date-format

I have a list to be exported to an Excel file keeping the appropriate format, I resorted to a library named xlsxwriter,

here is an example : 
[xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/tutorial03.html)

and here is my list  :

```
{'FirstName': u'Forence','LastName': u'Bidorst', 'Salary': -6775000.0, 'BirthDate': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 20, 0, 0)}
{'FirstName': u'Oliver','LastName': u'Bidorst', 'Salary': -6775000.0, 'BirthDate': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 20, 0, 0)}
{'FirstName': u'Mathew','LastName': u'Stark', 'Salary': -6775000.0, 'BirthDate': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 20, 0, 0)}
{'FirstName': u'Sphed','LastName': u'liomst', 'Salary': -6775000.0, 'BirthDate': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 20, 0, 0)}
```

I modified the code to browse a list and insert it into the file,

```
def export_result_XL():
 list=get_list()
 ...

 # Write some data headers.
 worksheet.write('A1', 'First Name', bold)
 worksheet.write('B1', 'Last Name', bold)
 worksheet.write('C1', 'Salary', bold)
 worksheet.write('D1', 'Birth Date', bold)

 # Some data we want to write to the worksheet.

 for entry in list:
     x = str(entry['FirstName'])
     y = str(entry['LastName'])
     z = str(entry['Salary'])
     e = str(entry['BirthDate'])
     v = BirthDate[:10]  # because the date format is like yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00

     expenses = (
             [x,y ,z ,v]
                 )

 # Start from the first cell below the headers.
 row = 1
 col = 0
for item ,str1,str2,str3,date_str in (expenses):
 # Convert the date string into a datetime object.
 date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d")

 worksheet.write_string  (row, col,     str1              )
 worksheet.write_string  (row, col + 1,     str2              )
 worksheet.write_string(row, col + 2,     str3              )
 worksheet.write_datetime(row, col + 3, date, date_format )


     row += 1

 # Write a total using a formula.
 #worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Total', bold)
 #worksheet.write(row, 2, '=SUM(C2:C5)', money_format)

 workbook.close()

 return ''
```

I had two problems here :

1 -

```
 for item, date_str in (frais) 
        ValueError: too many values ​​to unpack
```

2- 
if I avoid to convert to date format the file will be genreated but columns and rows are flipped

Is there any Idea how to do it , I hope I was clear in the description

Comment: What is the output format you are expecting? Why are you iterating over *and* unpacking `expenses` (which is a four-item list, the parentheses are irrelevant)? Why don't you use meaningful variable names (`x` is a first name? Come on!)?

Comment: I edited the description to make it clearer , 
my demand is simple : how to insert a list into excel file with managing the cell format (date , string , number ...)

Comment: Your *"demand"*?! What do you think this is? `expenses` is only the last `entry` from `list` (which you shouldn't name `list`). You are trying to write the same `item` to three separate columns; shouldn't that be three different values? I suggest you put in some `print`s and see what your data actually looks like.

Comment: shall i call it a dictionary instead of a list ? ,ok  you are right , so how can I do it

Comment: ...why would you do that? It is a list, not a dictionary, but if you name it `list` you prevent access to the built-in `list`. This isn't a code-writing service; I suggest you read http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: In fact I'm new in python coding  , I successfully exported this List of List to a csv file , but without formatting cells () , so I'm trying to export it to an excel file and controle the data format (date or string or number ) , I'm stuck for a long time in this example and I don't know how to do it exactly .!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a Solution :

```
 row = 1
 col = 0
 for entry in list:
    print entry

    strdate=str(entry['BirthDate'])
    formatdate=strdate[:10]
    date = datetime.strptime(str(formatdate), "%Y-%m-%d")

    worksheet.write_string  (row, col,     entry['FirstName']              )
    worksheet.write_string  (row, col+1,     entry['LastName']              )
    worksheet.write_number  (row, col+6,     entry['Salary'],number_format  )
    worksheet.write_datetime(row, col+10,    date, date_format )
    row += 1

 workbook.close()
```